# How to concatenate string and numbers to make a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to make a JSON object like this:

```
let lob =  { courses_dept: 'sci', courses_avg: 77.09 };
```

by concatenate variables together:

```
var dept = "sci";
var avg = 77.09;

let a = '{"courses_dept": dept, "courses_averge": avg }';
```

but I got SyntaxError if I do this:

```
let b = JSON.parse(a);
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do?  `let a = '{"courses_dept": "' + dept + '", "courses_averge": ' + avg + ' }';`

Comment: You can't make a [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). The docs says, that "_... It can't be called or constructed_"

Comment: **The** JSON object (i.e. the one and only) is a built-in ECMAScript object. What you have is an [*object initializer*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-object-initializer), aka literal, it is not a "JSON object".

Answer (score 1):

Note JSON stands for JavaScript Object **Notation**. JSON is *always* a string. It is a string *representation* of your encoded data. There is no such thing as *"a JSON Object"*.

Don't attempt to write JSON by joining strings and other values together. Instead build an object and pass it to `JSON.stringify` -

```js
const dept = "sci"
const avg = 77.09

// make an object
const myobject = { courses_dept: dept, courses_average: avg }

// use JSON.stringify to encode myobject to JSON
const myjson = JSON.stringify(myobject)
console.log("encoded", myjson)

// test JSON.parse to decode the JSON and get the object back
console.log("decoded", JSON.parse(myjson))
```

```js
encoded {"courses_dept":"sci","courses_average":77.09}

decoded {
  "courses_dept": "sci",
  "courses_average": 77.09
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use strings:

```
var dept = "sci";
var avg = 77.09;

let a = `{"courses_dept": "${dept}", "courses_averge": ${avg} }`;
```

This assumes that `dept` is a string. If you don't know this in advance, wrap each variable with `JSON.stringify`:

```
let b = `{"courses_dept":   ${JSON.stringify(dept)}
         ,"courses_averge": ${JSON.stringify(avg)}}`;
```

Notice that the string uses backticks ` instead of regular quotes. This allows you to do [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You can use + if you want to do straight up concatenation.

You can also just do a regular object:

```
let c = {"courses_dept": dept, "courses_averge": avg}
JSON.stringify(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just plain <strike>json</strike> object then?

```js
var dept = "sci";
var avg = 77.09;

let a = {
  "courses_dept": dept,
  "courses_averge": avg
};

console.log('a', a);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way works and seems to be simpler.

```
let b = {};
b["courses_dept"] = dept;
b["courses_averge"] = avg;
```

Comment: Here `b` is a JavaScript _Object_. This has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a serialization format for sending JavaScript data as _strings_ for storage or communication across a network, etc. You can also write this as a simple object literal, `let b = { courses_dept: dept, courses_average: avg }`

Answer (score -2):

You can make a JSON with single quotes and concatenate variables. After that you can parse the string.

```
var id_of_the_product =  $('#is-a-gift').data( 'gift_product_id' ) ;

var items_in_cart = (cart_item_count) - (gift_wraps_in_cart);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/update.js', 
    data: JSON.parse('{ "updates": { "'+ id_of_the_product +'" : "'+items_in_cart+'" }, "attributes": { "gift-wrapping": "'+gift_wrapping_type+'" } }'), 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {  } 
  });
```

Comment: Why a -1 vote? Because of a bad practice. The concatenation might fail in the case when the variables concatenated are of type object and parsed with `JSON.parse`. You'll get "[object Object]" instead of some usable data in the parsed json result. Which means you might lose data at server side.

Comment: Also, the $.ajax post data property should be stringified by using `JSON.stringify()`. Not a parsed JSON string. But that was not the question at all ^^